# run mysql without collation (utf-8 only)

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I run a sqlite3 database with utf8-strings from many languages. For various reasons I want to move to mysql, but I constantly run into trouble because of the mysql-collation feature.

One problem is that I am not even able to reliably know what is in my database. (For example I get "?" for non-latin characters and "�" for latin-based characters like öé, etc. - but I have absolutely no idea whether the problem lies in the import from sqlite3 to mysql or in reading from the mysql-database.)

Is there a way to get rid of this "feature" and let mysql do what I tell it without trying to be smart? I use UTF-8 everywhere and I never need any mangling of strings: Input is always UTF-8 and output should be always UTF-8. Also I really would like to know what *really* is stored in the database - i.e. without a collation-feature corrupting the data during readout.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MySQL [`VARBINARY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) column type, which stores a sequence of arbitrary bytes without interpreting them in any particular charset (or maybe `VARCHAR BINARY`, which is [subtly different](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-collations.html)).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses `latin1_swedish_ci` unless you specify something different explicitly. That's the opposite of smart. *You* have to be smart and change that default. This can be done with e.g.  the [`--character-set-server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server) and [`--collation-server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_collation-server) command line options. See [Specifying Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-syntax.html) for other means and further options.